# Multiple instances of class using synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, concurrency, synchronized

I'm programming something right now where I have multiple instantiations of an object all running in separate Threads. I want to have a synchronized method that only one instantiation of the object can execute at a time. I know the `synchronized` keyword won't work since that only works for a single instantiation of the object and making the whole method `static` is not really an option. Currently I am using a `static` `boolean` that the Threads check to see if the method is occupied along with a `Thread.sleep()` method call. It looks like this:

```
    while(occupied){
        Thread.sleep(randomGenerator.nextInt(1000) + 500);
    }

    occupied = true;
    int bufferLength = outputBuffer.size();

    System.out.println(name + "Size=" + outputBuffer.size());
    System.out.print(name + ": ");

    for(int i=0; i<bufferLength; i++){
        System.out.print(outputBuffer.take().get("Order Number") + ",");
    }

    System.out.println("\n" + name + " is finished.\n");

    occupied = false;
```

`boolean` `occupied` is the static variable being shared between 4 instantiations of my object.

This is getting me the desired results, but I feel like putting the Threads to sleep for a random amount of time is a messy way to get the output I want, and also still has a very small chance to go wrong. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

final note: this if my first time posting here so if there is something I did wrong please let me know.

edit: fixed the code a little bit

Comment: For clarification, is the closing bracket on line 3 of your code intentional?

Comment: Oh oops, I missed that. When I copied and pasted the code I left out the try block that everything is in but I must have grabbed the closing brace on accident. The brace on line 3 is intentional, but the brace at the very bottom is not. I will edit that out and fix the indentations.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to synchronize on a shared lock object:

```
private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

public void foo() {
    synchronized(LOCK) {  
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.